# Cron wont create directories

Tags: shell, cron, cron-task

I have **crontab** entry , cannot find a problem with it, but it does not work.

```
*/5 * * * * mkdir -m /home/ubuntu/aus/cron/$(date +\%Y\%m\%d)/$(date +\%R) && /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/aus/test.py >> /home/ubuntu/au/cron/$(date +\%Y\%m\%d)/$(date +\%R)/cron.log 2>&1
```

I am trying to make **cron** to make directory inside **cron** folder and put the cron log file inside it.

Comment: use `mkdir -p` do create multiple directories at once.

Comment: That cron entry is getting sufficiently complicated that I'd move it into a script, and then cron executes the script.

Comment: is there a simple script  to add this to and run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this as `/home/ubuntu/aus/test.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/bash

rootdir=/home/ubuntu/aus
crondir=$(date "+$rootdir/cron/%Y%m%d/%R")

mkdir -p "$crondir"
/usr/bin/python3 "$rootdir/test.py" >> "$crondir/cron.log" 2>&1
```

And then the cron entry will be

```
*/5 * * * * /home/ubuntu/aus/test.sh
```

The magic of `mkdir -p` is that a) it creates each missing directory in the path and b) it does not error if the directory already exists.

Comment: when i do **bash test.sh**, it works..But cron is not running the script..Do i need to execute change permission of **test.py** file ?

Comment: You either (1) give `test.sh` execute permissions, or (2)  in cron use `bash /path/to/test/sh`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have an error in your `mkdir` statement. The `-m` argument is for setting the mode of the directory you're creating. You need to either get rid of the `-m` or provide it with a meaningful argument (eg. `mkdir -m 755 ...`).

Comment: i added mkdir -m 755, wont work. i used a test case : */2 * * * * mkdir -m 755 /home/ubuntu/aus/test is working, but the actual problem statement wont

Comment: you might want to consider adding '-p' switch in case some part of the directory you're trying to create doesn't exist. And/or look at your cron.log log file...

Comment: it's but... if I try to create /a/b/c/d where b,c,d directories don't exist, it won't work...

Comment: No, `mkdir` will not by default create intermediate directories. That's what the `-p` switch is for. You could also just redirect the output from mkdir to an existing location and inspect any errors you're getting.

Comment: if i dont pass the **date** part, everything works fine. But i need to pass the **date** as folder name (YMD) format

Comment: it doesnt exist

Comment: then add '-p' to create intermediate dirs - not just the last one

Answer (score 0):

I lost a few hours to this. I couldn't get cron to make a file or directory. It was because I assumed cron would run from `/`, but in fact, it was running from `/root` (so the directories/files were being created the whole time, but when I looked for them, I couldn't see them in `/` so I assumed they hadn't been created.

I figured this out by running this:

```
* * * * * pwd >> /cronlog.txt 2>&1
```

after 1 minute I checked it:

```
cat cronlog.txt
/root
```

Lesson learned.